# Generate list of regex expressions to replace list of words in a dataframe python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm trying add new column headers to a dataframe which may conflict with existing dataframe headers.

I would like to use `df.replace(to_replace, replacements, regex=True)` to replace any whole words that match existing df columns with a word from the replacements list.

As an example:

If current `df.columns = ['Test 1', 'Test 2']`

I would like to replace all strings of 'Test 1' in the df with 'Test 1_Test 1'

If I use:

```
df.replace(r'\bTest 1\b', 'Test 1_Test1', regex=True)
```

I can replace just the instances of 'Test 1', however I would like to generalize this to be able to replace all instances of the column headers with a different word.

My understanding of the root cause is I am not generating a list of regex expressions correctly and would like to know how.

Currently I am using:

```
replace_list = list( r'\b' + pd.Series(list(df.columns)) + '\b')
```

However this does not work.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Try `r'(?:\b|(?<=_))(?:' + pd.Series(list(df.columns)) + r')(?=\b|_)'`. If `pd.Series(list(df.columns))` is like `word1|word2|etc` it should work. A similar soluton: `r'(?<![^\W_])(?:' + pd.Series(list(df.columns)) + r')(?![^\W_])'`.

Comment: I just tried the first example, it worked - thank you!

Can you explain the logic briefly?

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer, but I am using a mobile, it may take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variable you pass to the regex pattern seems to look like `word1|word2|more_here`, you may use

```
r'(?:\b|(?<=_))(?:' + pd.Series(list(df.columns)) + r')(?=\b|_)'
```

This pattern will match one of the alternatives in between word boundaries or underscores. The reason for the alternations inside the lookbehind and lookahead is that a word boundary by itself requires a non word char on either side of the search word, and that means underscores, being word characters, would fail the match.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider [upvoting the answer that turned out useful for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to replace the all the values in a column if it matches the header label.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'],
                 ['aa','Test2','cc','dd','ee'],
                ['aa','bb','cc','Test4','ee'],
                ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee']])
df.columns=['Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4','Test5']

print df

cols=pd.Series(df.columns)


for col in cols:
    replacevalue=col+'_'+col
    df[col] =df[col].replace(col,replacevalue)
print df
```

input

```
  Test1  Test2 Test3  Test4 Test5
0    aa     bb    cc     dd    ee
1    aa  Test2    cc     dd    ee
2    aa     bb    cc  Test4    ee
3    aa     bb    cc     dd    ee
```

output

```
  Test1        Test2 Test3        Test4 Test5
0    aa           bb    cc           dd    ee
1    aa  Test2_Test2    cc           dd    ee
2    aa           bb    cc  Test4_Test4    ee
3    aa           bb    cc           dd    ee
```

Comment: This is changing the df column headers. I am looking to replace text within each column if it matches any of the headers.

Comment: Make sure that you update the question; right now it is little misleading

Answer (score 0):

Try to think differently of this task - it's much easier and much much faster to rename the original **column** names:

```
In [228]: df
Out[228]:
                       Test 1                      Test 2
0              Will this work  Test 2: Is this even legit
1  Test 1: Maybe it will work                        nope
2   It probably will not work                        nope

In [229]: df.add_prefix('~~').add_suffix('~~')
Out[229]:
                   ~~Test 1~~                  ~~Test 2~~
0              Will this work  Test 2: Is this even legit
1  Test 1: Maybe it will work                        nope
2   It probably will not work                        nope
```

Comment: This seems to edit the original df columns. I am interested in replacing the text in the df if they match the df columns. Using your example if a column header was "Will" then the "Will" text should be replaced with "Will_Test 1" throughout the df.